# Using EHLAPI32 in C# with RUMBA as an emulation vendor

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll, mainframe

Can anybody give me introduction to Use EHLAPI32.dll in C# with RUMBA as the emulation vendor.
I have to fetch data from a mainframe.

Answer (score 1):

The following link into the IBM EHLLAPI documentation explains how to send and receive files to and from a mainframe or midrange computer.

[Introduction to IBM Standard EHLLAPI, IBM Enhanced EHLLAPI and WinHLLAPI Programming](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pcomhelp/v5r9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.pcomm.doc/books/html/emulator_programming07.htm)

If you're still needing help on the C# side, there are articles that show how to use EHLLAPI from a C# application. While I couldn't locate one that specifically sends and receives files, the following article and code show how to use EHLLAPI from C#.

Therefore, you can read the following (CodeProject) article to figure out how to use EHLLAPI from C# and then read the IBM docs to understand the semantics of the specific EHLLAPI functionality you are wanting to leverage.

[Using EHLLAPI in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9615/Using-EHLLAPI-in-C)

By the way, this all assumes you're sending/receiving files; not data into a data source (such as an AS/400 database).

If the latter is what you're looking for, I'd probably use ODBC if what you're doing is something fairly basic and you're not needing a lot of advanced functionality (such as two-phase commit, or TPC).

Comment: TS has used the Mainframe tag, so no reason to suspect AS/400, is there?

Comment: True. I'm just used to always saying "mainframe or midrange" when the information applies to either category.

Comment: TS may return. From the Mainframe I'd argue for the other way around. File-transfer via FTP/NDM etc, "automation" (if that is what is wanted) through the emulator. We don't like data getting "out" which is not under "our" control :-) The file-transfer on Rumba I'd hope to find diasbled... I'd imagine similar for a Midrange, but no personal experience...